# How to download or install php7.2-curl extension in ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: php, curl

I want to install curl extension in my current php-project(php version is 7.2.34) for that i use this command sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl it's throwing following error and it's not showing in the list when i run php -m command ,How to install curl extension please help me to fix this issue..

```
[sudo] password for payarc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-curl : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.44.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`Error when i am doing composer update`

```
The requested PHP extension ext-curl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
```

Comment: apt-get install php7.2-curl

Comment: when i am doing this command only i am getting above error

Comment: This isn't really a programming question as such. Try on https://askubuntu.com

Comment: What you got by running this command `sudo apt-get install -y libcurl3`

Comment: @Joseph,unable to find package libcurl13

Comment: try `libcurl4` it may works

Comment: Libcurl14 is installing but php7.2-curl shows same error

Comment: Write your question in askubuntu they will help you more than here